# Java String equals

Tags: java, string, equals

```
DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                                               receiveData.length);

_socket.receive(receivePacket);

String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());

InetAddress IPAddress = receivePacket.getAddress();

int port = receivePacket.getPort();

if(sentence.equals("hello")) (...)
```

Question: Why `sentence.equal("hello")` isn't true when sentence is `"hello"`? Is it because of String's Constructor `String(byte[])`?

Who can I deal with that?

Thanks

Comment: What if you print sentence, like System.out.println(sentence) ?

Comment: It's because whatever it is you're comparing it to *isn't* `hello`. The debugger is your friend, and will answer your question :)

Comment: Odds are there's a line ending character or some whitespace in there. Ultimately, @BrianRoach is right.

Comment: You can do this to see if there is whitespace: `System.out.println("[" + sentence + "]")`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your string probably contains `"hello"` but is padded with other junk. You could try

```
if (sentence.trim().equals("hello")) {...}
```

---

To illustrate:

```
String s = new String(new byte[]{0, 1, 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 2, 3});
System.out.println(s.equals("hello"));
System.out.println(s.trim().equals("hello"));
```

```
false  
true
```

---

**Relevant documentation**

- [`trim`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `System.out.println ("[" + sentence + "]");` or examine the variable in a debugger if you can - you may find the string is not what you expect, such as having a newline character at the end for example.

The chances of a bug in `String.equals()` is vanishingly small :-)

Comment: Or simply use the debugger and look at the contents.

Comment: @paxdiablo `System.out.println("[" + sentence + "]")` might print `[hello]` even when the string is not `"hello"`.

Answer (score 0):

Here packets are received through sockets. There is a chance of inclusion of extra spaces. I can't simulate the scenario because, data are coming via socket .Apply trim() on the sentence and try again.